# Get around no constructor in interface, in java

Tags: java, selenium, junit

So, I am wondering how I can get around the fact I can't have a constructor in an interface?

I am doing test automation with JUnit and Selenium. I have a base test class that has a method called `getDriver(LoginPage loginPage)`. This method is used to initialize web driver. LoginPage is an interface that has a login method. The problem is all my page objects constructors take a web driver. And the getDriver method inits the web driver. So, my question is how can I initialize the page object in this method with only the interface? Thanks

```
public interface LoginPage {

    public BasePage signIn(String user, String password); 

}

    //can't init LoginPage outside, since I need this method to init WebDriver
    public static WebDriver getDriver(LoginPage loginPage)
    {
    if (WebDriverUtil.hasQuit()) {
        log.debug("Creating new instance of driver");
        BaseTest.init();

        browser = region.getBrowser().getName();

        driver = WebDriverUtil.initDriver(browser, baseURL);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT/1000 );
        SeleniumUtil.waitForPageLoaded(driver,DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
        if(loginPage != null)
        {
            loginPage.signIn(user, pass);
        }
    }       
    return driver;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using reflection to solve this problem.

```
public static <T extends LoginPage> WebDriver getDriver(Class<T> loginClass)
{
    if (WebDriverUtil.hasQuit()) {
        log.debug("Creating new instance of driver");
        BaseTest.init();

        browser = region.getBrowser().getName();

        driver = WebDriverUtil.initDriver(browser, baseURL);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT/1000 );
        SeleniumUtil.waitForPageLoaded(driver,DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);

        handleLogin(driver, loginClass);
    }       

    return driver;
}

private static <T extends LoginPage> void handleLogin(WebDriver driver, Class<T> loginClass)
{
    if(loginClass != null)
    {
        try {
            Constructor<T> constructor = loginClass.getDeclaredConstructor(WebDriver.class);
            try {
                T loginObj = constructor.newInstance(driver);
                loginObj.signIn(user, pass);
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                    | IllegalArgumentException
                    | InvocationTargetException e) {
                log.warn("Error instantiating object for class: " + loginClass.toString());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            log.warn("No constructor that takes WebDriver is present on class: " + loginClass.toString());
            log.trace(e);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            log.warn("SecurityException present on class: " + loginClass.toString());
            log.trace(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you making a generic WebDriver anyway? Aren't you supposed to be using the existing browser-specific implementations or `HtmlUnitDriver`?

Comment: WebDriver is just the interface. I have a method WebDriverUtil.initDriver(browser, baseURL) that will init either a ChromeDriver or IEDriver or Firefox driver based on a system property.

Answer (score 0):

You would create an anonymous class on the spot or implement the interface in a different class and instantiate that.

Although using Java code to enter passwords doesn't seem like such a good idea especially when it is in the form of a `String`

Comment: As mentioned this is for test automation purposes, we have test IDs we are leveraging, hence the lack of security.